# Using HTML in job description for Jenkins job generated by DSL

Tags: html, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm migrating some Jenkins jobs to DSL code from the current manual configurations. Some of these jobs have descriptions which contain HTML, but I can't find a way to enter this HTML in the seed job so that the generated job contains the same description. In one example, the current job has this description:

```
Multi-Platform Build <br/><br/>

Builds nightly but only if there has been SCM revisions against the application Core Trunk. <br/><br/>

This is being replaced by <a href="http://myjenkinsserver/view/application/job/application-new">application-multi-platform-new</a>
```

Which results in a nicely formatted job description with line breaks and a hyperlink as well.

I want to replicate this when I generate the same job from a DSL script but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible with just specifying the html-tags that you need. What is your output?

```
    description("""
Multi-Platform Build <br/><br/>

Builds nightly but only if there has been SCM revisions against the application Core Trunk. <br/><br/>

This is being replaced by <a href="http://myjenkinsserver/view/application/job/application-new">application-multi-platform-new</a>
    """)
```

Comment: OK, I did try that earlier, but like everything else in my DSL scripts my description was contained in ('Multi...') rather than the three sets of double quotation marks you specified, which works. Thanks! Not sure why this is required though and haven't seen it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Maybe you needed expansion? 3 """ or 3 ''' just means multiline. And ' you don't get variable expansion. With " you get variable expansion. Not sure if that was the problem. Anyway, great that it worked, you are also able to indent the string and then you stripMargin()

Comment: That was the problem I think because as soon as I change this back to how I had it before it breaks, but doing it your way work - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a workaround but I'd prefer to do this directly.

It's possible to use the below snippet:

```
job('multi-platform-build') {
    description(readFileFromWorkspace('description.html'))
}
```

This allows you to have a separate file the workspace of the seed job which is called to provide the description.

This works but it's far from ideal as this means configuration being stored in two separate locations.